# Replace numbers with letters and offer all permutations

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, python-itertools

I need to determine all possible letter combinations of a string that has numbers when converting numbers into possible visually similar letters.

Using the dictionary:

```
number_appearance = {
       '1': ['l', 'i'],
       '2': ['r', 'z'],
       '3': ['e', 'b'],
       '4': ['a'],
       '5': ['s'],
       '6': ['b', 'g'] ,
       '7': ['t'],
       '8': ['b'], 
       '9': ['g', 'p'],
       '0': ['o', 'q']}
```

I want to write a function that takes an input and creates all possible letter combinations. For example:

```
text = 'l4t32'

def convert_numbers(text):
      return re.sub('[0-9]', lambda x: number_appearance[x[0]][0], text)
```

I want the output to be a list with all possible permutations:

```
['later', 'latbr', 'latbz', 'latez]
```

The function above works if you are just grabbing the first letter in each list from `number_appearance`, but I'm trying to figure out the best way to iterate through all possible combinations. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists)

Comment: I notice that in the list of all possible permutations you replace the `r` with `z`, but you do not replace the `l` with `i`. Why is that?

Comment: I am only replacing numbers with letters that appear like them. The `l` isn't replaced because it is already a letter. If I had used the number `1` instead of the letter `l` than I would want a version that used both `l` and `i`.

Comment: But the `r` is already a letter also! I think you need to remove `'latbz'` and `'latez'` from the list of permutations.

Comment: Oops - that is a mistake on my part - the `r` should have been a `2` in the example :)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - I was able to put together a solution based on your reference above. Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, you will probably find it simpler and more efficient to use [the `translate` method of strings](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to do the multiple replacement logic, rather than that regex-based approach. I will add an answer in order to show this technique.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thanks - it seems i didn't `re.sub` when using the Cartesian product way... if you have other suggestions to make what I posed below more efficient or elegant, lmk!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an upgrade from your own answer, I suggest the following:

```
    def convert_numbers(text):
        all_items = [number_appearance.get(char, [char]) for char in text]
        return [''.join(elem) for elem in itertools.product(*all_items)]
```

The improvements are that:

- it doesn't convert text to a list (there is no need for that)
- you don't need regex
- it will still work if you decide instead that you also want to add other characters on top of numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert_num_appearance(text):
    string_characters = [character for character in text]
    
    all_items = []

    for item in string_characters:
        if re.search('[a-zA-Z]', item):
           all_items.append([item])
        elif re.search('\d', item):
           all_items.append(number_appearance[item])

    return [''.join(elem) for elem in itertools.product(*all_items)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would break down the problem like so:

1. First, create a function that can do the replacement for a given set of replacement letters. My input specification is a sequence of letters, where the first letter is the replacement for the `'0'` character, next for `1` etc. This allows me to use the index in that sequence to determine the character being replaced, while generating a plain sequence rather than a dict or other complex structure. To do the replacement, I will use the built-in `translate` method of the original string. That requires a dictionary as described [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), which I can easily build with a dict comprehension, or with the provided helper method `str.maketrans` (a static method of the `str` type).
2. [Use `itertools.product`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists) to generate those sequences.
3. Use a list comprehension to apply the replacement for each sequence.

Thus:

```
from itertools import product

def replace_digits(original, replacement):
    # translation = {ord(str(i)): c for i, c in enumerate(replacement)}
    translation = str.maketrans('0123456789', ''.join(replacement))
    print(translation)
    return original.translate(translation)

replacements = product(
   ['o', 'q'], ['l', 'i'], ['r', 'z'], ['e', 'b'], ['a'],
   ['s'], ['b', 'g'] , ['t'], ['b'], ['g', 'p']
)

[replace_digits('14732', r) for r in replacements]
```

(You will notice there are duplicates in the result; this is because of variant replacements for symbols that don't appear in the input.)